# Django rest framework simple model serializer list view takes forever to show 10 records

Tags: python, django, performance, django-rest-framework, django-debug-toolbar

I have this model -

```
class News(BaseEntityBasicAbstract, HitCountMixin):
    """
    News added from the dashboard with content
    """
    NEWS_STATUS = (
        ('draft', _('Draft')),
        ('pending', _('Pending')),
        ('review', _('Review')),
        ('public', _('Public')),
        ('private', _('Private'))
    )
    backup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    prev_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGES, default='bn', db_index=True)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_('News Heading'),
                               help_text=_('Provide a news heading/caption.'))
    sub_caption = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_('Summary'),
                                   help_text=_('Provide summary of the news.'))
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name=_('URL/Slug/Link'),
                           help_text=_('Unique url for the news without whitspace.'))
    content = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Content'),
                        help_text=_('HTML content with texts, links & images.'))
    featured_image = models.FileField(upload_to=FilePrefix('news/'), null=True, blank=True,
                                      verbose_name=_('Featured Image'),
                                      help_text=_('Upload a featured image for news.'))
    image_caption = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,
                                     verbose_name=_('Image Caption'),
                                     help_text=_('Provide a image caption.'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=NEWS_STATUS, default='pending',
                              verbose_name=_('News Status'), db_index=True,
                              help_text=_('Only public news can be seen on front end.'))
    source = models.ForeignKey(NewsSource, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_('News Source'),
                               help_text=_('Select a news source.'))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 verbose_name=_('Category'),
                                 help_text=_('Select a news category.'))
    tags = tagulous.models.TagField(
        blank=True,
        to=Tags,
        verbose_name=_('News Tags'),
        help_text=_('Provide news tags separated with commas.')
    )
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True,
                                        verbose_name=_('Published At'))
    menu_items = GenericRelation(MenuItems, object_id_field='id',
                                 related_query_name='news_as_menu')
    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk',
                                        related_query_name='news_hit_count')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='news_created_by',
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_('Created By'))
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='news_updated_by',
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_('Last Updated By'))
    published_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='news_published_by',
                                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                     verbose_name=_('Published By'))
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='news_deleted_by',
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name=_('Deleted By'))
```

Below is the serializer -

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ['id', 'heading', 'sub_caption', 'url', 'content', 'featured_image',
                  'image_caption', 'category', 'source', 'tags', 'published_at']
```

This is the view -

```
class NewsViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.filter(
        is_active=True,
        status='public'
    )
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(
            language=self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE
        ).order_by('-id')

        return queryset
```

Pagination is set to only 10 in the settings.py, when I hit the news api url it takes 9/10 seconds to load only 10 records. Here's a screenshot showing django-debug-toolbar reports -

[image: djdt image for drf view]

I have around 400k records on the database table, it may be an issue, but I think this is too much loading time. Please help me find the problem here! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just noticed that, if I get rid of the "status='public'" filter it loads in 200 ms. I'm quite confused, why/how the 'status' choice filed's making the query time that much slow!!

Comment: If it's mostly caused by filtering on the `status` field, you should try adding an index in the database and seeing if that helps. Ah, I see you already have an index, but you might need a composite index as you're filtering on multiple fields.

Comment: Note also that LIMIT / OFFSET pagination is very slow for higher offsets. If it's possible (you don't need page numbers) I'd suggest using DRF's cursor pagination instead.

Comment: status field is set as index. I believe there are some issues with MySQL index fields, because now I'm switched app db to postgres and everything works fine with the same query and filtering. This is quite confusing to me about the index related issue of MySQL.

Comment: If you're using MySQL you're a bit limited. I'm formulating an answer that should help however. It seems like the `is_active` field is missing from your model, also.

Comment: is_active field is defined in an abstract class with some common fields to add on each table, as you can see the model uses BaseEntityBasicAbstract class. I believe now that MySQL allows limited index support for queries. I've tested the query generated from Django on MySQL workbench, query time was quite slow. I've started to feel disappointed in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering can often be slow. It looks like you have database indexes on the relevant fields, but take note that if you have multiple filters, only one of the indexes will be used.

I'm guessing based on your columns but it seems like the most common query will always be looking for `is_active=1` and `status='public'`. If this isn't the case you might have to make some tweaks.

Firstly, get rid of the `db_index=True` on the `status`, `is_active`, and `language` fields, otherwise your database writes will be slowed unnecessarily.

Then you can formulate an index such as this:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(
            fields=["is_active", "status", "language"],
            name="idx_filtering",
        )
    ]
```

This will help the database when you filter on all three columns at once. If you're ever filtering on only one of these columns however, you may want to keep the original `db_index=True`.

If you were using PostgreSQL, you could do one better:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(
            fields=["is_active", "status", "language"],
            name="idx_filtering",
            condition=Q(is_active=True, status="public"),
        )
```

This would reduce the size of the index to only those matching the `Q()`, making traversing it faster.

One other thing to note is that pagination using `OFFSET` is very slow once you get to higher offsets. If at all possible you should be using DRF's cursor pagination instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom Carrick. Gave me some awesome ideas. I'll be trying out these kind of indexing. I have to keep the single indexes for the admin list querysets. I was stuck on index together of these fields.

Comment: @MahmudAbdurRahmanToki if you do find the answer useful, please upvote and accept the answer - that's how the site works.